# Dynamodb total record count for Pagination

Tags: dynamodb-queries

I am planning to leverage AWS DynamoDB for one the legacy application. I have did the data modelling for persist the data in DDB and I have came with single table, as it is coming to effective in my use case.
But, there is one of the requirement where I need to show the total qualified record count for a Query for Pagination.
Apart of Scanning the whole table, is there any out of box to to get total qualified record counts?

Thanks

Comment: that's a no for dynamo

Answer (score 0):

> You can use describe table API for that.
>
> It will return several json values including **ItemCount** which you
> need.

This might be not 100% updated as of its no-sql nature. They update it after every ~6 hours. If you need live count, you have to scan entire table but scan is also eventually consistent operation.

> If your question is about count on the basis of some condition then
> no, you have to use scan or query depends how you want to implement
> conditions

more details
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/describe-table.html